# C++ тесты для валидации UTF-8

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты, utf-8, utf

Мне нужно написать unit тесты для валидации UTF-8, но не понимаю, как указать некорректную UTF-8 строку в С++:

```
TEST(validation, Tests)
{
    std::string str = "hello";
    EXPECT_TRUE(validate_utf8(str));

    // I need incorrect UTF-8 cases
}
```

Можно ли как-то указать некорректную UTF-8 строку в С++ для тестов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да элементарно

```
std::string a = "\0x80\0x80";
```

ну и тому подобное.

или так

```
std::string a = "\0xFF\0xFF";
```